# triggering to page load event when textbox value is changed

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to trigger page load event when textbox value is changed.For example to search.When I write on textbox anything page load event will be trigged.

Comment: In visual studio form designer, if you select the textbox, look at the properties window and click the lightining icon, that will show you the available event methods.
In that window you should be able to find one for onTextChanged or similar. If you write a method name for it in there and hit enter, it should create an empty method for you which you can call your page load event from.

Comment: Do you really mean that you want to call Page_Load on each and every keystroke (value change) in your textbox?  Can you tell us more about what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Re-loading the page just by typing into a textbox would result in an *awful* user experience.  You're much better off triggering the page post-back from a button click or at least an 'enter' keystroke which submits the form.  Or, even better, fetching the search result data via AJAX so the page doesn't have to refresh at all.